# WAF policy - block and allowlist regulation

Tags: web-application-firewall

I want to block certain countries IP addresses in my WAF.  
Say I have a legitimate user trying to access the website from their mobile while they are on holiday in one of the blocked countries. Is it possible to allow them access by authenticating the user fist? 
I've been having issues finding any documentation to confirm if this is possible and how it would be done.